# Inside div <ol> is properly working but <ul> is not working. How to solve this?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

Inside div of bootstrap classes I want to create an **ul but it floats automatically but ol is working perfectly.** I searched in my best way for the solution in stackoverflow. If this problem had already answered my apologies.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 about-content">
                <h2>The short</h2>
                 <ul class="menu">
                    <li>item-1</li>
                    <li>item-2</li>
                    <li>item-3</li>
                    <li>item-4</li>
                    <li>item-5</li>
                </ul>  
                <h2>The long</h2>
                <p> content </p>       
            </div>
```

I applied KISS rule in CSS and any other possible solutions available in stackoverflow. But, I can't figure out the mistake. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just do it with ol and then remove the styling...

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: This is my whole code it's inside a <div> and the <div> is inside the <body> sir @D.Pardal Thank you for your response sir

Comment: Yes sir. But, I don't know why <ul> is not working that's why I posted sir @Soban Thank you for your response sir

Comment: @BhavaniKasiviswanathan do you have any CSS? If so, please add.

Comment: @BhavaniKasiviswanathan, What `css` do you have behind `about-content` class?

Comment: I edited your question to include Bootstrap and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Sorry sir it's working  but my whole navigaton bar is collapsed after adding those bootstrap @D.Pardal. I already tried this one sir. Can I olny apply those links to list alone? Is there anyway for that sir?

Comment: @BhavaniKasiviswanathan Please include the CSS code you wrote so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Now, I added the complete CSS Sir @D.Pardal

Comment: Yes sir @Manjuboyz

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this

> If you want list like `item-1 item-2 item-3 item-4 item-5`

```css
.about-content{
    margin-left: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #EFF0F1;
    width: 900px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    text-align: left;    
}

.menu{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left; 
}

.menu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;   /*Set display to inline-block to the ul*/
}

.menu li{
    text-decoration: none;
}


ul { text-align: center; }
ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 about-content">
      <h2>The short</h2>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>item-1</li>
        <li>item-2</li>
        <li>item-3</li>
        <li>item-4</li>
        <li>item-5</li>
      </ul>
      <h2>The long</h2>
      <p> content </p>
    </div>
```

Now `<ul>` or `Un-ordered list` displaying side-by-side properly.

> If you want list like

```
item-1
item-2
item-3 
item-4 
item-5
```

```css
.about-content{
    margin-left: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #EFF0F1;
    width: 900px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    text-align: left;    
}

.menu{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left; 
}

.menu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.menu li{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}


ul { text-align: center; }
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 about-content">
      <h2>The short</h2>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>item-1</li>
        <li>item-2</li>
        <li>item-3</li>
        <li>item-4</li>
        <li>item-5</li>
      </ul>
      <h2>The long</h2>
      <p> content </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: item-1 item-2 item-3 item-4 item-5 It displays like this sir

Comment: @BhavaniKasiviswanathan can you tell me how you want to display the list

Comment: I want to dsplay the list one by one. Like normally how the  list works like that

Answer (score 1):

> Remove `ul li { display: inline-block; }` when you make `inline-block` for `li` then it makes as same line OR inline.

```css
.about-content {
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #EFF0F1;
  width: 900px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  text-align: left;
}

#menu {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  /*Set display to inline-block to the ul*/
}

#menu li {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-6 about-content">
  <h2>The short</h2>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>item-1</li>
    <li>item-2</li>
    <li>item-3</li>
    <li>item-4</li>
    <li>item-5</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>The long</h2>
  <p> content </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I declared menu as id sir. So that I used #. Then If I add those Scripts my entire navigation bar is collapsed

Comment: @BhavaniKasiviswanathan here is working snippet for ID : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/d5temaso/3/

Comment: Yes sir it is working. But if I add the scripts my entire navbar above those are collapsed

Comment: The question you asked for SO is fixed, other issues may not be with the code you shared it may be with the other code you have in your place, so it is hard to say what is the issue, however this is the answer for the questions you asked.

Comment: Actually as you said the problem is fixed by both of the codes.But the problem  in navbar may be in other scripts I will figure it out

Comment: @BhavaniKasiviswanathan can you share `navbar` script to make it more clear about the problem